# Recover table records from months ago?

Tags: sql-server

We recently ran into a huge issue in which we lost critical usage information for the months of August-October 2019.

I have set out to try recover this data. I found our SQL Server 2017 database is set to full recovery thankfully because I read some threads that if this wasn't the case, then we would be out of luck.

With that, I'm trying to run a stored procedure I found here https://raresql.com/2012/04/08/how-to-recover-truncated-data-from-sql-server-without-backup/

I'm running into some permission issues but assuming I have permissions, would it be possible to recover such data from 3-4 months ago? I want to know before proceeding asking for permissions and wasting DBA's time. If not, are we truly outta luck? Could 3rd party tools like ApexSql work?

***Backstory if interested what's going on:***

What happened is the powershell script we have on our windows server generates csv files containing usage information from a usage table that gets updated every 5 mins with usage data and sends them over to a linux server via connect direct FTP service daily. Once the file is sent, the script truncates the usage table because we dont want to run into performance issues as data continues building up in 1000s of records daily.

At that point of time, we didn't consider archiving the export files but now we learned our lesson and started archiving them since. What happened was the ftp service stopped running on linux server and so no one was notified for 2 months about this, and management now sees a gap in the usage report for those missing months, and they're not happy about it.

Comment: "Wasting DBA's time? Yikes - this should be a responsibility of the DBA. And you should be having this discussion with your DBA and whoever is responsible for this database / system. The recovery model will not really help if you haven't been making backups on a regular basis. That procedure uses an undocumented function that uses the active portion of the transaction log. I'll guess this won't be much use, but it is impossible to know without trying. This question really belongs on [dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @SMor oh I didnt know about dba site. Thanks! And you're right, everyone should be involved in trying to recover this but everyone is careless and in vacation so I'm trying to tackle this myself before giving up just like that, especially as time goes by, the pages could probably become more overwritten and we may lose in the long run than trying in short run. On the bright side, I learned some very useful database concepts and finally understood atired procedures. They're basically functions you can call on a whim! I like that :)

Comment: @SMor ok so I met with a microsoft engineer and he told me to execute a query, the query displayed backup information. Apparently, he said theres no way to recover the data if theres no backup, but it looks like we have an EMC (3rd party company) backup taken automatically every day (yay!). The size is triple digit millions so I'm guessing we can indeed recover the 2.5 months truncated records afterall! We are just waiting on a DBA after the break to give us the MDF/LDF files cause they only have access to prod backups